# Layout files naming conventions?

Tags: android, layout, naming-conventions, android-layout

What are some layout file naming conventions people have come up with.

I haven't found anything online, but thought about using the following convention.

What does everyone think?

```
 - activity_* 
 - dialog_*
 - list_item_*
```

That's all I have worked with so far.

Also, what about the naming of the activity against its layout? For example:

```
-> res
    -> layout
        -> activity_about_us.xml
-> src
    -> activity
        -> AboutUs.java
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Strangely enough, trying to google this question brings only this page as meaningful result...
For the past half year I am using naming convention similar to yours but with shorter prefixes. For example:
For activity that shows "About us" screen:

**Class name**: `ActAboutUs`. Prefixing class is kind of overkill but it clearly distinguishes activity classes from the others. Initially I used separate directory for all the activities (similar to your approach) but after some time I realized that for bigger apps may be it is better to group in directories by feature than by superclass (i.e. Activity). It is easier for me to work in single directory for example `/src/settings/` when I work on Settings. That way all java files that I need are in a single dir so i don't have to wander around:

```
/src/settings/ActSettingsGlobal.java
/src/settings/ActSettingsNet.java
/src/settings/Settings.java
/src/settings/SettingsDBAdapter.java
/src/settings/etc...
```

This approach also helps to split the work among different developers, i.e. each one is working in his own dir on separate feature so no stepping on each other's feet :-).

Some people preffer suffixes but I found them less useful. Prefixes help to group things alphabetically like in the example above: `Act*` prefix is sorted first so all activities are conveniently at the top.

I am even considering of using `Act_` as a prefix which is more readable although it is in conflict with java naming conventions...

**Layout filename**: `act_about_us.xml`. In `res/layout/` we don't have the "luxury" of subdirs which is quite unfortunate so the only way to group things is using appropriate prefix like `act_`, `dlg_`, etc...

**String IDs**: `<string name="act_about_us_dlg_help1_title" ...`
`string.xml` is the place where we have most problems with duplicate `name`s. It is very easy to create duplicates if naming convention like `activity_element_item` is not used. It adds a lot of additional typing but it saves you from a lot of confusion later on. 
For global (application wide) strings we use prefix `"global_"`, for example `global_btn_ok`, `global_msg_no_inet_conn`. Usually we make one person responsible for all `global_` strings so if someone needs new string or change he needs to sync with him in order to avoid creating a mess.

(now I am realizing that `activity__element__item` (two underscores) is more clear and readable than `activity_element_item`)

All in all I still can't get rid of the feeling that there is something wrong with my approach because I can't believe that google devs created such an inconvenient framework when it comes to working with files, IDs, names, etc...

Comment: I was googling all over looking for some kind of guideline to follow myself which as you have discovered led me to post this question.

Comment: did you find a better solution?

Answer (score 9):

i think following naming convention should be follow

for activity

if our activity name is

```
DisplayListActivity
```

then our layoutname should be

```
display_list_activity.xml
```

for list items we can include category in list item layout name

```
country_list_item.xml
```

and for dialogboxes their action can be included

```
delete_country_dialog.xml
```

Answer (score 7):

When looking for a group of layouts, which is how I tend to work on them, I find it effective to always prepend the class name and follow up with any sub-layouts. For Instance:

**Class Name:** `AboutActivity.java`
**Layout Name:** `about_activity.xml`
**Sub-layout Name:** `about_activity_menu.xml`
**Sub Sub-layout Name:** `about_activity_menu_item.xml`

Your activity will always be at the top of each grouping and hunting for non-activities becomes less of a chore. Anyone know why sub-folders aren't a thing yet? I expect for efficiency and simplicity on the back-end, but I imagine it wouldn't hurt too much.

Answer (score 7):

This is a good read https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2016/03/07/resourcenaming/

Basically, you follow `WHAT WHERE DESCRIPTION SIZE`

[image]

For example, layout file

- activity_main: content view of the MainActivity
- fragment_articledetail: view for the ArticleDetailFragment

strings

- articledetail_title: title of ArticleDetailFragment
- feedback_explanation: feedback explanation in FeedbackFragment

drawable
 - all_infoicon_large: large version of generic info icon
 - all_infoicon_24dp: 24dp version of generic info icon

Answer (score 1):

The first part of a layout file name should always be the type of the corresponding class.
For example if we have a class `MainActivity` (type is `Activity` in this case), the corresponding layout file should be called `activity_main.xml`

That means that lets say we have a dialog called `WarningDialog`, the corresponding layout file should be called `dialog_warning.xml`, same goes for fragments etc.

This might seem familiar because thats also how the `activity/layout` files are named when creating a new project in Android Studio (`MainActivity` -> `activity_main.xml`).

Answer (score 1):

For me, naming should fix two important requirements:

1. **it should give you a hint about files' content and type**  (for example activity_login/login_activity or movie_list_item/list_item_movie)
2. **it should visually group related items together** to minimize jumping back and forth

For the second requirement, most people define "related" as type related which gives you something like this:

```
activity_login
activity_movie_list
activity_user_list
activity_settings
fragment_movie_list
fragment_user_list
item_movie 
item_user
```

etc.

I prefer to do grouping by feature since you'll almost never work on all activities or all fragments, but instead, you'll work on movies feature or setting feature.

so, my prefered way is this:

```
login_activity
movie_list_activity
movie_list_fragment
movie_list_item 
user_list_activity
user_list_fragment
user_list_item
settings_activity
```

Source files are following xml naming but in CamelCase, so there will be

```
LoginActivity
MovieListActivity
MovieFragment 
etc.
```