# Layout naming strategies for android

Tags: java, android, naming

I am developing an android app that has quite a few layouts. So far I have been naming these by what the layout is used for followed by a name for the layout eg: activity_base.xml, fragment_main_menu.xml. As I have noticed android supports no sub directories for the resources folders. Already with 12 layout files things are starting to get a bit cramped. I was wondering if anyone had any good naming strategies to keep this awful one directory setup organized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android doesn't support nested directories. So unfortunately you will have to chose naming conventions carefully.

Here's a link that discusses the naming conventions: [Layout files naming conventions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582079/layout-files-naming-conventions)

Answer (score 0):

What I always to is first of all determine the layouts that are for activity and the ones that are for fragment by starting the layout file with:

```
activity_<activity.name>
```

or

```
fragment_<fragment.name>
```

Of curse you have another types of layout like:  `ListView` item layout or a `Dialog` layout for example.

specify them at the beginning of the layout name so they would be easy for you to find.

Other then that give your layour proper names that explains exactly what it should present.

Answer (score 0):

You could logically categories layouts based on the `Activity` job instead.

Like `Home_Main.xml`.Then if there are some more logics attached to the menu.Say for instance it takes you to a facebook share activity from the Home then give it `Home_FB.xml`.Then if the FB page takes you to `pageB`,name that pageB layout as `FB_pageB.xml`.

I bet this way is best unless some one has something better.

To separate Listviews and other items you could as well start with LV like `LV_some_other.xml`