# Why is default naming convention for Activity and Layout, MainAcitivty.java and activity_main.xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, naming-conventions

After developing Android for a while, I kind of got used to for Activity class, we just name it `<something>Activity.java`, while it's layout as `activity_<something>.xml`, given the default Android Studio generated is this.

However when was asked why is this so (i.e. reverse the position of the activity word), I can't really confirm the real reason behind (though I have some idea). Hence asking all if there's a official reason why is it reversed between the Java class vs the XML layout file.

Checking if anyone have a good context behind why is this so... (didn't find anything on Stackoverflow or Android Developer site, but would be cool if there is, and someone could point me to).

(Note: I'm not asking opinion of this naming convention... but looking for any official reason of this naming convention)

Comment: I think one of the reason is you will feel easy if you use the auto-complete features of Intellj

Comment: If someone downvote this question, would appreciate to state the reason. I believe this question is useful, as the reason for a standard naming convention is something important for developer to understand. Thanks.

Comment: It seems there is no official reason about that. So the answers you might get will mainly from the experience of the developers. There are some related information about the naming convention of the android coding. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582079/layout-files-naming-conventions ,  https://github.com/ribot/android-guidelines/blob/master/project_and_code_guidelines.md

Comment: I did a research about naming conventions for layouts, menus, values and other resources and I found that actually there is no standard naming conventions. I didn't find any things that is recommended by google except the article that is about naming fields and ... . I also found many conflicts when working with different templates in android studio and also in google samples. Maybe the reason is that in alphabetic sort, activities, fragments and other layouts come inside together with current default naming convention. So feel free to choose any naming conventions you want!